# remove chapter number from section entries in tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, titlesec

an MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp,backref=true,backrefstyle=two+,hyperref=true,isbn=false,backend=biber,citereset=chapter,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]%
{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]%
{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]%
{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]%
{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\cfoot{}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Second Chapter}
 \section{first section}
 \section{second section}
\end{document}
```

The table of contents looks like this:

[image]

I want to remove the chapter number from all entries that are `section`,`subsection` and lower (i.e remove the A. from A.1 and so on).

This should only affect the table of contents, so no redefinition of `\thesection` is allowed. I think using titlesec would be optimal, I just don't know how to do it.

E.g replace the proper things in

```
\titlecontents{section}
[3.8em] % ie, 1.5em (chapter) + 2.3em
{}
{\contentslabel{2.3em}}
{\hspace*{-2.3em}}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Never load `a4wide`: it's buggy and its job is done much better by `geometry`.

Comment: If the sections in the text are numbered “A.1” and so on, they should have the same numbering in the table of contents.

Answer (score 2):

With `titlesec` you can change `\thesection`, `\thesubsection` locally  inside headings using `\titleformat` to obtain numbering `A.1`, `A,2` for section and `A.1.1`, `A.1.2` for subsection.

And defining  `\thesection`, `\thesubsection` for  all document also inside toc with:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}}
```

---

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp,backref=true,backrefstyle=two+,hyperref=true,isbn=false,backend=biber,citereset=chapter,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]%
{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]%
{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]%
{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]%
{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\cfoot{}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}}


\titleformat{\section}
{\Large\bfseries} {\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\large\bfseries} {\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thechapter.\thesection\arabic{subsection}}\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Second Chapter}
 \section{first section}
 \section{second section}
 \subsection{first subsection}
\end{document}

Result
```

[image]